# Cannot inject view to custom class with RoboGuice

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, roboguice

I started to use [RoboGuice](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice) within my project. I can easily inject views inside fragments and activites but i have some trouble with cusom views.
I got null ptr exception every time.

According to [RoboGuice's example](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Your-First-Injection-into-a-Custom-View-class) i did the same with my custom class:

**TestActivity**

```
@ContentView(R.layout.test_layout)
public class TestActivity extends RoboActivity {

    @InjectView(R.id.testView_1) TestView testView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

**TestView**

```
 public class TestView extends LinearLayout {


    @InjectView(R.id.log_in_tab) View logInTab;

    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initView();
    }


    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        if (logInTab == null)
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Still NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void initView() {

        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.login_view, this);
        RoboGuice.injectMembers(getContext(), this);
    }


}
```

Login view's xml is in [pastebin here.](http://pastebin.com/WVsmJ9Vf)

**Test layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <view
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="hu.illion.kwindoo.view.test.TestView"
        android:id="@+id/testView_1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Toast always says that **`logInTab`** is null.

Please help if you can.

Comment: not see a `R.id.log_in_tab` in your layout.

Comment: @JiangYD It was in pastebin but somehow the link is broken so i edit the post.

Comment: @JiangYD Cannot edit the post, the edit button is inactive, dont know why.

Comment: @JiangYD Pastebin is reachable again.

Comment: have no idea.  `android annoations` is simpler and better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why there is no code examples of that but when i have to inject custom views i use injectViewMembers.

Hope this work for you:

```
public void initView() {
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.login_view, this);
    RoboGuice.injectMembers(getContext(), this);
    RoboGuice.getInjector(getContext()).injectViewMembers(this);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm i havent seen any code example like this either, but this definetly works. Thank you, now time for reducing code base like hell :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answer, you should use the following method to actually start using the injected views:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    someTextView.setText("Some text");
}
```